# How to achieve facebook new page link ui view?

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, android-viewpager

I have my ".com" web page and a "facebook page". When sharing a link from my "facebook page" and someone opens the link in the mobile it opens chrome bwoser and shows the content.

However, I notice that some links from other facebooks pages when open only slides from right to left and shows content.

I have tried to look it but on how to achieve this same effect for my page but I have found nothing.

Can someone point me to the right direction on how to do this? Tutorials, documentation or any information about it. [Image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uj39X.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example illustrates the high-level structure of an Instant Article. For more detail on each element, refer to the specific details in the Elements section of this document.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" prefix="op: http://media.facebook.com/op#">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/article.html">
    <meta property="op:markup_version" content="v1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <article>
      <header>
        <!-- The title and subtitle shown in your Instant Article -->
        <h1>Article Title</h1>
        <h2>Article Subtitle</h2>

        <!-- The date and time when your article was originally published -->
        <time class="op-published" datetime="2014-11-11T04:44:16Z">November 11th, 4:44 PM</time>

        <!-- The date and time when your article was last updated -->
        <time class="op-modified" dateTime="2014-12-11T04:44:16Z">December 11th, 4:44 PM</time>

        <!-- The authors of your article -->
        <address>
          <a rel="facebook" href="http://facebook.com/brandon.diamond">Brandon Diamond</a>
          Brandon is an avid zombie hunter.
        </address>
        <address>
          <a>TR Vishwanath</a>
          Vish is a scholar and a gentleman.
        </address>

        <!-- The cover image shown inside your article --> 
        <figure>
          <img src="http://example.com/path/to/img.jpg" />
          <figcaption>This image is amazing</figcaption>
        </figure>   

        <!-- A kicker for your article --> 
        <h3 class="op-kicker">
          This is a kicker
        </h3>

      </header>

      <!-- Article body goes here -->

      <!-- Body text for your article -->
      <p> Article content </p> 

      <!-- A video within your article -->
      <figure>
        <video>
          <source src="http://example.com/path/to/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
      </figure>

      <!-- An ad within your article -->
      <figure class="op-ad">
        <iframe src="https://www.adserver.com/ss;adtype=banner320x50" height="60" width="320"></iframe>
      </figure>

      <!-- Analytics code for your article -->
      <figure class="op-tracker">
          <iframe src="" hidden></iframe>
      </figure>
  <footer>
    <!-- Credits for your article -->
    <aside>Acknowledgements</aside>

    <!-- Copyright details for your article -->
    <small>Legal notes</small>
  </footer>
</article>
```

Also, you can have a look at this tutorial - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/faq/